# Docker Kafka client to Docker Kafka broker connection refused

Tags: .net, docker, apache-kafka, docker-compose

As the title states I am having issues getting my docker client to connect to the docker broker

Errors:

```
%3|1647161877.851|FAIL|fc24c271e73f#producer-1| [thrd:localhost:9092/bootstrap]: localhost:9092/bootstrap: Connect to ipv4#127.0.0.1:9092 failed: Connection refused (after 0ms in state CONNECT, 1 identical error(s) suppressed)
2022-03-13T08:57:57.851241551Z %3|1647161877.851|ERROR|fc24c271e73f#producer-1| [thrd:app]: fc24c271e73f#producer-1: localhost:9092/bootstrap: Connect to ipv4#127.0.0.1:9092 failed: Connection refused (after 0ms in state CONNECT, 1 identical error(s) suppressed)
```

Server setup:
Community docker-compose.yml from step 1 of guide:

https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/quickstart/ce-docker-quickstart.html

Client setup:

```
.NET Confluent.Kafka producer
```

Procedures so far:
I initially thought it would be an issue with localhost in the docker container and using docker option:

```
--net=host
```

also fixed the issue. However this has the side effect of removing published ports and is no good.

I then tried using

```
--add-host host.docker.internal:host-gateway
```

which I found in another post (cannot remember which) however this does not work.
I initially thought there was an issue with it since the --net=host works but when I tried it with a SignalR sample project it worked straight away.

I have come across multiple posts suggesting changes to

```
KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS
```

However I find it odd that the host forwarding is not working and changes to this would make a difference.
I have nonethelss tried out multiple combinations of it whether it be the broker ip of localhost to 0.0.0.0 etc. (stuff I found across different posts) but with no success.

Trying to get a better understanding of what is going on I came across this post:

https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-client-cannot-connect-to-broker-on-aws-on-docker-etc/

Which explains the 2 step process involved in connecting to a broker.
Looking at the errors I received with the /bootstrap it seems to already fail on the initial connection. This however should be an indication that the immediate issue is not with with KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS however I may be wrong in that assumption.

The post does have a docker to docker scenario but that is being done using custom network bridge which I do not want to have to use for this.

Anybody has any ideas of what I should do? Perhaps knows the exact changes to make and where.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears your code is trying to connect to port 9092.

`PLAINTEXT://broker:29092` is the listener you want to connect to, assuming your own code is in a container, as well.

If it isn't, then you can use `localhost:9092` without host networking, but you need to have these variables

```
KAFKA_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://broker:29092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://0.0.0.0:9092 
KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://broker:29092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:9092
```

> done using custom network bridge

Compose defaults to create its own network bridge unless you define one separately and link all services to it.

> not want to have to use for this.

You'll need a bridge unless you're running the code on a Linux host where `--net=host` will actually work. Then you should be able to use `localhost:9092`.

You shouldn't need host networking, though, if you understand how the listeners work

> has the side effect of removing published ports

Not exactly. The exposed ports of the container should automatically be exposed on the host

Comment: Thanks for reply.
I had already tried many combinations between code,docker and listeners. For the above it was simply connecting to localhost:9092.
The KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS is already set like this in the compose file.
Adding KAFKA_LISTENERS causes the broker(cp-server) to no longer start up.
Is --add-host not an option? In which case I would have to use custom network bridge (client is not part of compose).
"has the side effect of removing published ports" I wrote this incorrectly. I meant to say the mapped ports

Comment: Adding `KAFKA_LISTENERS` shouldn't prevent the broker from starting. You'll need to show the logs that include any error that happened when you added that. And no, `--add-host` is not the correct solution to the problem you're having; using a bridge network is. Why not add to the same compose file? What is wrong with using `--network` flag?

Comment: I got it working and you are right. Using --network makes more sense. I have different solutions each with separate projects that can communicate with Kafka so keeping it as a separate docker-compose makes more sense. This way I can up it on its own and do the projects separately.